# How to write the JSON structured data to a text file in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to write my JSON structured data to a JSON file. `js` dataframe contains the JSON data like this:

```
[{"variable":"Latitude","min":26.845043,"Q1":31.1972475},{"variable":"Longitude","min":-122.315002,"Q1":-116.557795},{"variable":"Zip","min":20910.0,"Q1":32788.5}]
```

But when I write it to a file, the data gets stored differently. Could you please help me to store the result as like it is in the dataframe(js)?

```
"[{\"variable\":\"Latitude\",\"min\":26.845043,\"Q1\":31.1972475},{\"variable\":\"Longitude\",\"min\":-122.315002,\"Q1\":-116.557795},{\"variable\":\"Zip\",\"min\":20910.0,\"Q1\":32788.5}]"
```

Code:

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\spanda031\Downloads\DQ_RESUlT.csv')
js = df.to_json(orient="records")
print(js)

# Read JSON file
with open('C:\\Users\\spanda031\\Downloads\\data.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(js,data_file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
# it will dump json to file
df.to_json("filename.json", orient="records")
```

Output as **filename.json**:

```
[{"variable":"Latitude","min":26.84505,"Q1":31.19725},{"variable":"Longtitude","min":-122.315,"Q1":-116.558},{"variable":"Zip","min":20910.0,"Q1":32788.5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're double-encoding your data - `df.to_json` converts the data to a JSON string. Then you're running `json.dump` which then encodes that already-encoded string as JSON again - which results in wrapping your existing JSON in quote marks and escaping all the inner quote marks with a backslash You end up with JSON-within-JSON, which is not necessary or desirable.

You should use one or other of these methods, but not both together. It's probably easiest to use `df.to_json` to serialise the dataframe data accurately, and then just write the string directly to a file as text.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\spanda031\\Downloads\\data_new.csv','w')
df.to_csv(js)       I used this to write it to a csv but still the result is same

Comment: how can writing it to a CSV produce the same result? That has nothing to do with encoding as JSON. And if `js` is JSON why would you try to write it as CSV? That makes no sense. Just write it as plain text. It seems someone has demonstrated the correct way to you now, so hopefully there's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Talk is so cheap ,why not let me show you the code ?

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\spanda031\Downloads\DQ_RESUlT.csv')
// where magic happends! :)
js = df.to_dict(orient="records")
print(js)

# Read JSON file
with open('C:\\Users\\spanda031\\Downloads\\data.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(js,data_file)
```

Comment: Thank you. and +1 for (Talk is so cheap ,why not let me show you the code ?)